# How to display custom post types using single-[post_type] and archive-[post-type]?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm having a bit of a problem with my custom post types... My post type is called 'videos'. I have all of the posts showing on their single page using the 'single.php' template. But when I take the post name out of the url and keep /videos/, I get a 404 - but I want to list all of the 'videos' here. I tried using archive-videos.php file as the codex reccomends: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types, still with no luck. It also says you can do single-videos.php for custom post types, but this doesn't work either. I'll display the code I use to register my post type below, am I doing something wrong?

```
add_action('init', 'videos_register');
function videos_register() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Videos', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Video', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'question'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Video'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Video'),
        'new_item' => __('New Video'),
        'view_item' => __('View Video'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Videos'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
      ); 
    register_post_type( 'videos' , $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the arg 'has_archive' => true. Hope this helps!

Comment: Damn... as easy as that. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting a 404 error when attempting to reference the custom post archives. The following lines solved my problems:

```
...
'rewrite' => true,
'has_archive' => true
...    
register_post_type( 'post_type' , $args );    
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

I also had to make sure my permalink structure was:

```
/%postname%/
```

Answer (score 0):

i also found this link as an alternative 
http://en.bainternet.info/2011/custom-post-type-getting-404-on-permalinks

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late may be but important to mention that …

```
'has_archive' => 'my-example-archive' // True/False
```

… or explicitly mentioning the slug i.e `news`, `events` etc and than disable the permalinks and again reactive after saving will solve the issue.